# Compare values in a list

Tags: f#

Trying to conceptualize how I would compare several values in a list to find the largest value, without using mutable variables.

For example in an imperative language I could simply store a max variable that gets updated every time the iteration finds a larger value in the list. Like such:

```
max = 0;
for i in list
  if i > max
    max = i
```

Now, in functional programming if i had a list, for example [1; 2; 3]
How would I get around the issue of using a max variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer would be to use `let maxValue = List.max theList`.

If you were wanting to 'roll your own' without using an explicitly mutable variable, the obvious way is to use a recursive function.  Personally, I would define it like so:

```
let listMax theList = 
    let rec maxHelper remainingList maxSoFar = 
        match remainingList with
        | [] -> maxSoFar
        | h :: t -> 
                      if h > maxSoFar then
                          maxHelper t h
                      else
                          maxHelper t maxSoFar

    maxHelper theList (List.head theList)
```

Note that this implementation as presented would throw an exception with an empty input list (also, I haven't actually tested this, so there *might* be a slight error in there).  The reason I have done it this way is that it uses tail recursion, which should mean it's roughly as efficient as a mutable solution, but keeps the complexity of the exposed function signature to the bare minimum.

Alternatively, this could also be done fairly easily with a List.fold call.  E.g.

```
List.fold (fun (nextElem, maxSoFar) -> 
    if nextElem > maxSoFar then nextElem else maxSoFar) (List.head theList) theList
```

Same proviso about not having tested it applies to this too.

In both of the presented cases, this could be made more generic to apply to any binary operation that returns a boolean, by using another parameter that is a function which carries out said operation.  E.g.

```
List.fold (fun (nextElem, maxSoFar) -> 
        if comparatorFunction nextElem maxSoFar then nextElem else maxSoFar)
        (List.head theList) theList
```

Comment: Instead of using `List.fold`, you could also just use `List.reduce max`. The `List.reduce` function (of type `('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'a list -> 'a`) is perfect for this situation, where you want to reduce the list to a single element. Apart from that, a mutability-based solution is of course perfectly valid as well. In fact, that's how the `List.max`-function is [implemented in FSharp.Core](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L572).

Comment: @torbonde Both very good points, thanks for mentioning them :) I personally had wanted to avoid using the max function though, as I felt it was a bit 'cheaty' here. In normal circumstances I would prefer your solution to either of my latter two though.